# Need help PowerShell script for RAM check

Tags: powershell

I'm using Windows Terminal Server, and I need help. Some user use a lot of RAM, so I hope you can help me with a script to check RAM per users and sending message for user who uses 5GB+ memory.

I found a script to check RAM per user.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |
    select @{N='User';E={$_.GetOwner().User}}, WorkingSetSize |
    group user |
    select Name, @{N='CPU';E={($_.Group.WorkingSetSize | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 1Mb}}
```

Comment: What is your question here? If you expect us to rewrite code you found somewhere else to fit your requirements: that is not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Question is how to connect Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |
    select @{N='User';E={$_.GetOwner().User}}, WorkingSetSize |
    group user |
    select Name, @{N='CPU';E={($_.Group.WorkingSetSize | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 1Mb}} to  Send-RDUserMessage. I dont know possible this or dont

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" questions is usually "yes". What you need to do is check if the size of the used memory is above a particular threshold (5GB in your case) and if so send the notifications. You need a `ForEach-Object` and an `if` for that. If you find yourself unable to make even an attempt at implementing this you need to find a PowerShell tutorial first. SO is not a replacement for familiarizing yourself with the language you're using.